# How to generalize a macro to any row

Tags: vba, macros

The Excel macro below is written to function on a specific row (row 2) of Excel.
I would like to be able to apply it to any row that I select rather than just to row 2.
Does anyone know how to adapt it? I had this written for me and do not know any VBA coding.

```
Sub test()

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

ie.Navigate "http://www.fedex.com/us/"

While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

ie.Visible = 1

Set doc = ie.document

On Error Resume Next

With doc

    .getElementsByname("username").Item(0).Value = "Username"
    .getElementsByname("password").Item(0).Focus
    .getElementsByname("password").Item(0).Value = "Password"
    .getElementsByname("startpage").Item(0).selectedindex = 1
    .getElementsByname("login").Item(0).Click

    While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

    Set doc = ie.document

    doc.getElementsByname("toData.addressData.contactName").Item(0).Value
= Range("L2")

    doc.getElementsByname("toData.addressData.addressLine1").Item(0).Value
= Range("M2")

    doc.getElementsByname("toData.addressData.city").Item(0).Value = Range("N2")

    doc.getElementsByname("toData.addressData.zipPostalCode").Item(0).Value
= Range("P2")

    doc.getElementsByname("toData.addressData.phoneNumber").Item(0).Value
= Range("S2")

    doc.getElementsByname("psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].weight").Item(0).Value
= Range("F2")

    doc.all("psdData.packageType").Value = "Your Packaging"

    Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("psdHandler_onShipPackageTypeChange(""IS3_GSV="")", "JavaScript")

    ie.document.getElementsByname("psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].mpsDimensionSelect").Item(0).Item(1).Selected
= True

    Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("psdHandler_onChangeDimensions()", "JavaScript")

    ie.document.getElementsByname("psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].mpsLength").Item(0).Value
= Range("g2")
    ie.document.getElementsByname("psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].mpsWidth").Item(0).Value
= Range("h2")
    ie.document.getElementsByname("psdData.mpsRowDataList[0].mpsHeight").Item(0).Value
= Range("i2")

    .getElementbyid("module.rating._headerButtons").Click

    ie.document.getElementbyid("rating.calculateRate").Click
     End With

Set doc = Nothing Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following as the first line:

```
activeRow = ActiveCell.Row
```

This will give you the currently selected row. Then replace every cell which relates to row 2 by

```
"X" & activeRow
```

where X is the column name which already exists in your code.

Comment: That works for me.